# Showing null pointer exception even though no error is showing up

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This is the code MainActivity.java file. I think there should be no mistake in this code. But it shows the message

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference.
```

I don't know why it is showing up there? Please help me to figure out.

```
package com.example.android.practiceset2;

import android.os.Bundle;            
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;`


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int score=0,wickets=0;
String value=null,number=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i1);//b_i1 stands for increase in 1 run taken by team B and similarly other names are to the ids of different button.
Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i2);
Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i3);
Button b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i4);
Button b6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i6);
Button bw=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_w);
Button bwide=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_wide);
Button a1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_i1);
Button a2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_i2);
Button a3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_i3);
Button a4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_i4);
Button a6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_i6);
Button aw=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_w);
Button awide=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_wide);
TextView ta= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.a);
TextView tb= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.b);


public void aorb(View view{
if(getResources().getResourceEntryName((view.getId())).startsWith("a"))
{ value="a";}
else{value="b";}
    number=getResources().getResourceEntryName((view.getId())).substring(2);
    score();}

   public void a_enabled(Boolean b)
{
    a1.setEnabled(b);
    a2.setEnabled(b);
    a3.setEnabled(b);
    a4.setEnabled(b);
    a6.setEnabled(b);
    aw.setEnabled(b);
    awide.setEnabled(b);
}
public void b_enabled(Boolean b)
{
    b1.setEnabled(b);
    b2.setEnabled(b);
    b3.setEnabled(b);
    b4.setEnabled(b);
    b6.setEnabled(b);
    bw.setEnabled(b);
    bwide.setEnabled(b);
}

public void display(String s){
    if(value.equals("a"))
    {
    ta.setText(s);
    b_enabled(false);
    a_enabled(true);
    }
    else {
        tb.setText(s);
        a_enabled(false);
        b_enabled(true);
    }
}

public void score(){
   int i=0;
    if(number.equals("i1"))
   i=1;
    if(number.equals("i2"))
        i=2;
    if(number.equals("i3"))
        i=3;
    if(number.equals("i4"))
        i=4;
    if(number.equals("i6"))
        i=6;
    if(number.equals("wide"))
        i=1;
    score+=i;
    if(number.equals("w"))
        wickets+=1;
    if(wickets==10)//if a team loses all its 10 wickets , the score is finalised and next team is invited for play
    {
        display(score+"/"+wickets);
        if(value.equals("a"))
        {
            value="b";
        }
        else{value="a";}
        score=0;
        wickets=0;
        display(score+"/"+wickets);
    }
    display(score+"/"+wickets);
}

public void reset(View view){
    ta.setText("0/0");
    tb.setText("0/0");
    a_enabled(true);
    b_enabled(true);

}}
```

This is the code for my content_main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Team A"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:textColor="#616161"
       android:layout_margin="16dp"
       />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="56dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/a"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:onClick="aorb"
        android:id="@+id/a_i1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:onClick="aorb"
        android:id="@+id/a_i3"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:onClick="aorb"
        android:id="@+id/a_i6"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:onClick="aorb"
            android:id="@+id/a_i2"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:onClick="aorb"
            android:id="@+id/a_i4"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Out"
            android:onClick="aorb"
            android:id="@+id/a_w"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Wide"
            android:onClick="aorb"
            android:id="@+id/a_wide"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
   android:layout_width="2dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"></View>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team B"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="56dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/b"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="aorb"
                android:id="@+id/b_i1"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:onClick="aorb"
                android:id="@+id/b_i3"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:onClick="aorb"
                android:id="@+id/b_i6"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:onClick="aorb"
                android:id="@+id/b_i2"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:onClick="aorb"
                android:id="@+id/b_i4"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Out"
                android:onClick="aorb"
                android:id="@+id/b_w"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Wide"
            android:onClick="aorb"
            android:id="@+id/b_wide"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the image of it should look like [it is the screenshot the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClIsg.png)

Comment: There are quite a few problems with your code as posted, I don't know how you got it to compile. I would start by moving all of your logic for initializing your buttons and any view to inside of the onCreate(...) methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these `findViewById` must be included in your `onCreate()` method. You can keep the declarations out of `onCreate()`. Your views do not exist before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

I mean before `onCreate()` you can have `Button b1;`  
and after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onCreate()` you must have `b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i1);`  
**for every view**.

Comment: I even tried to place views after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 0):

I have made the corrections in your and now the app is not crashing. Try using the below code snippet

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score = 0, wickets = 0;
    String value = null, number = null;

    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    Button b3;
    Button b4;
    Button b6;
    Button bw;
    Button bwide;
    Button a1;
    Button a2;
    Button a3;
    Button a4;
    Button a6;
    Button aw;
    Button awide;
    TextView ta;
    TextView tb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_i1);//b_i1 stands for increase in 1 run taken by team B and similarly other names are to the ids of different button.
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_i2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_i3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_i4);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_i6);
        bw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_w);
        bwide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_wide);
        a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_i1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_i2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_i3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_i4);
        a6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_i6);
        aw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_w);
        awide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_wide);
        ta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        tb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);

    }

    public void aorb(View view) {
        if (getResources().getResourceEntryName((view.getId())).startsWith("a")) {
            value = "a";
        } else {
            value = "b";
        }
        number = getResources().getResourceEntryName((view.getId())).substring(2);
        score();
    }

    public void a_enabled(Boolean b) {
        a1.setEnabled(b);
        a2.setEnabled(b);
        a3.setEnabled(b);
        a4.setEnabled(b);
        a6.setEnabled(b);
        aw.setEnabled(b);
        awide.setEnabled(b);
    }

    public void b_enabled(Boolean b) {
        b1.setEnabled(b);
        b2.setEnabled(b);
        b3.setEnabled(b);
        b4.setEnabled(b);
        b6.setEnabled(b);
        bw.setEnabled(b);
        bwide.setEnabled(b);
    }

    public void display(String s) {
        if (value.equals("a")) {
            ta.setText(s);
            b_enabled(false);
            a_enabled(true);
        } else {
            tb.setText(s);
            a_enabled(false);
            b_enabled(true);
        }
    }

    public void score() {
        int i = 0;
        if (number.equals("i1"))
            i = 1;
        if (number.equals("i2"))
            i = 2;
        if (number.equals("i3"))
            i = 3;
        if (number.equals("i4"))
            i = 4;
        if (number.equals("i6"))
            i = 6;
        if (number.equals("wide"))
            i = 1;
        score += i;
        if (number.equals("w"))
            wickets += 1;
        if (wickets == 10)//if a team loses all its 10 wickets , the score is finalised and next team is invited for play
        {
            display(score + "/" + wickets);
            if (value.equals("a")) {
                value = "b";
            } else {
                value = "a";
            }
            score = 0;
            wickets = 0;
            display(score + "/" + wickets);
        }
        display(score + "/" + wickets);
    }

    public void reset(View view) {
        ta.setText("0/0");
        tb.setText("0/0");
        a_enabled(true);
        b_enabled(true);

    }
}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Team A"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="0/0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="56dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/a_i1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/a_i3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="3" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/a_i6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="6" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/a_i2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="2" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/a_i4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="4" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/a_w"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="Out" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/a_wide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:onClick="aorb"
                    android:text="Wide"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"></View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Team B"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="0/0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="56dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b_i1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b_i3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="3" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b_i6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="6" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b_i2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="2" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b_i4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="4" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b_w"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="aorb"
                        android:text="Out" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b_wide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:onClick="aorb"
                    android:text="Wide"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:onClick="reset"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.